# How to update AWS Secrets Manager using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to update one of the value in the AWS Secrets Manager using NodeJS. I tried to do the below functionality. There is an Access Token(oAuth Token) saved initially in the Secrets Manager. This token is used for making API service calls from the lamda functions. So before invoking any service , the existing token in the Secretes Manager is fetched and the validity of the token is checked. If the token is expired, a new oAuth token will be fetched and this needs to be updated to the Secrets Manager.

Below is the Secret Manager update function. But it looks like the updateSecret method is not getting executed at all. Because I am not getting any success or error response . I also tried by giving SecretManagerReadWrite permission for the lamda function.

Is there any steps that I am missing here ?

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const region = process.env.REGION;

const secretName = "ProjSecrets";

// Create a Secrets Manager client
let client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
    region: region
});

const updateSecretManger = async (updatedSecretData) => {
    console.log("Update Secret Data : " + JSON.stringify(updatedSecretData));
    const params = {
        SecretId: secretName,
        SecretString: JSON.stringify(updatedSecretData)
    };
    return await client.updateSecret(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error in updating Secrets Data : " + JSON.stringify(err));
        } else {
            console.log("Secret Manager updated : " + data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How this code triggered?

Comment: I have created a lamda function in which the codes will be executed in the below sequence  1) Fetch Secrets data 2) Check Token details 3) Get new token 4) Updated token to secrets manager. I have provided the code for the 4th point

Comment: How the lambda function is triggered?

Comment: From another lamda function in real time. So far i was testing with in console itself. Issue got resolved after using Promise. `const updateSecretsData = async (secretData) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {`